# How to build a route from point "A" to point "E" with the condition that the end point is the point "E"?

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I need to build all possible routes from point "A" to point "E" with the condition that the end point is a point "B"

**Task example:**

From : A, To: B

**Example result:**

A -> E

A -> B -> E

A -> C -> D -> E

A -> B -> C -> D -> E

So far I was able to do so:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..10 OUTBOUND "city/907499" GRAPH 'CityToCity' 
  FILTER p.edges[*].user ALL == "6609844"
  FILTER p.vertices[4]._id == "city/1012911"
RETURN p
```

But in this example, you must explicitly indicate at what level the endpoint should be located. How to make it simple from A to E without specifying level 4 in this filter "p.vertices [4] ._ id" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the AQL documentation says:

```
// access last array element
u.friends[-1]
```

So in your example, specify the constraint on `p.vertices[-1]._id`

Also specify a very large number for MAX. Unfortunately, currently AQL requires that a specific value be given, but a ridiculously large value can be specified.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it!
Can you help with one more problem? 
[Here is the task.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657397/how-to-use-witnin-with-2-geo-indexes-in-one-collection)