# How to use WITHIN with 2 geo indexes in one collection?

Tags: arangodb

I have 2 geo indexes in the collection.
I need to find all the documents on the first geo-index and another time on another geo-index.

```
LET cFrom =  (
FOR c IN WITHIN("city", 22.5455400, 114.0683000, 3000, "geofrom")
    FOR r IN rcity 
        FILTER r._from == c._id && r.user == "5010403" && r.type == "freight-m"
        LIMIT 1
RETURN r)

LET cTo =  (
FOR c IN WITHIN("city", 55.7522200, 37.6155600, 3000, "geoTo")
    FOR r IN rcity 
        FILTER r._to == c._id && r.user == "5010403" && r.type == "freight-r"
        LIMIT 100
RETURN r)
```

Comment: Please clarify the goals and the question.

Comment: How do I choose a specific geo index when using the WITHIN function?
I have 2 [geo-indexes](http://prntscr.com/ibqwg1)
I want the first geo index to be used in the first case, and in the second the second geo index